# Ошибка 500 при отправке POST запроса через ajax на laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Форма

```
<form id="contactform" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contactform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/test',
      data: $('#contactform').serialize(),
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Роут

```
$router->post('test', 'PostController@testf');
```

Контроллер

```
public function testf(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

В результате получаю ошибку 500

Comment: Ошибка 500 - это внутренняя ошибка сервера. В таких случаях - какая-то ошибка в php-коде. Дело не в Аяксе

Comment: смотрите в логи. Покажите что в логи пишется в этот момент.

Comment: Если про storage-logs, он не видит ошибки. Очищаю лог, отправляю запрос, лог пустой

Comment: попробуйте изменить в роуте пост на гет

Comment: Поменял, при обращении через форму выдает ошибку 500, при прямом переходе по ссылке /test страницу открывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь скорее всего ошибку выдает CSRF посредник. Попробуй закомментировать его в `App\Http\Kernel.php`
Ну и очень желательно не использовать `dump()` и `dd()` в ajax запросах. Используй `print_r` (`var_dump`) при условии, что запрос не json.

Comment: Ошибка была в выводе, ajax не мог принять результат с dd()